# Install Docker stable on Ubuntu following Docker Docs

Tags: 20.04, docker

I went to backup my /home and restoring to a fresh install on ubuntu 20.04. I reinstalled docker from docs and I've tried with adding user to group docker without using sudo. Still coming across

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-10-24 17:30:00 CDT; 4ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 79450 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 79450 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I ran the /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock and same output "Needs to be run as root in order to start" I run all the commands with sudo and previous installed on another machine worked fine. I did a complete purge and remove and autoclean and clean of docker and did a fresh install and same error.